# Lua For Variable In Range

Tags: variables, printing, lua, range

I can't seem to get this to work. I come from Python, so I tried using the same syntax for the hell of it, but it unsurprisingly wouldn't work:

```
var = 4

for var in range(2,20) do
print ("var is in range")
      end
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to test whether a value is in a range, use

```
if var>=2 and var<=20 then
   print ("var is in range")
end
```

If you want a loop, use

```
for var=2,20 do
   print(var)
end
```

Comment: Python ranges exclude the `stop` value, so the equivalent Lua loop would have been `for var = 2, 19 do ... end`.

Answer (score 4):

You could write your `range` function easily enough:

```
function range ( from , to )
    return function (_,last)
            if last >= to then return nil
            else return last+1
            end
        end , nil , from-1
end
```

Comment: That'd would be a for generator but the OP seems to want a condition tester.

Comment: I don't think so; see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function . Obviously using a numeric for loop is the correct solution; but he can still have his generator if he wants ;)