# Lua - generate sequence of numbers

Tags: lua, int, sequence

How do I generate a sequence of integer numbers based on first and last number for `for` to loop over?

The following pseudocode

```
for i in sequence(4,9) do
  print(i)
end
```

should produce the following output

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Please include a short explanation what the solution does in the background and what terminology would have allowed one to find the solution.

Search attempts lead to unsearchable huge pages of documentation.

Comment: I found that i=4,9 is the solution thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020574/lua-for-variable-in-range but I would ask for an explanation of what this does and what it is called. "," is unsearchable. Similar to trying to find "in" in Pythons documentation. :)

Comment: It is called a for loop?!

Comment: https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#3.3.5

Comment: "Search attempts lead to unsearchable huge pages of documentation"... any documentatation is searchable. if you want to do any programming you better get used to reading documentations. that's 99% of the work...

Comment: A simple `for` loop should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numeric for loop](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) to do that. You will find details in Programming in Lua section I referenced or the Lua manual section on [For statement](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5).

Answer (score 2):

Just for the full record, there are basically 3 ways you could do this loop, one with a slightly different syntax, and 2 with the exact syntax as your pseudocode. Links point to relevant chapters in [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) (which is a great book to read, by the way).

1) Using a simple [numeric for loop](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) - in this case you won't use `sequence`:

```
for i=4,9 do
  print(i)
end
```

2) Implement `sequence` as a [closure](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html):

```
function sequence(from,to)
  local i = from - 1
  return function()
    if i < to then
      i = i + 1
      return i
    end
  end
end

for i in sequence(4,9) do print(i) end
```

3) Implement `sequence` as a [coroutine](https://www.lua.org/pil/9.3.html):

```
function sequence(from, to)
  return coroutine.wrap(function()
    for i=from,to do
      coroutine.yield(i)
    end
  end)
end

for i in sequence(4,9) do print(i) end
```

Comment: ``function sequence(from,to,ind)
   local ind = ind or 1
   local i = from - ind
   to = to+ind
   return function()
      i = i + ind
      return i < to and i or nil
   end
end``

Comment: Just a suggestion for simplifying and adding more functionality :)