# Definition of f(x) in Lua documentation

Tags: lua

While trying to completely understand the solution to [Lua - generate sequence of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679600/), the [section 4.3.4 of Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) is unclear:

> ```
> for i=1,f(x) do print(i) end
> for i=10,1,-1 do print(i) end
> ```
>
> The for loop has some subtleties that you should learn in order to
>   make good use of it. First, all three expressions are evaluated once,
>   before the loop starts. **For instance, in the first example, f(x) is
>   called only once.** Second, the control variable is a local variable
>   automatically declared by the for statement and is visible only inside
>   the loop. [...]

The first line of code doesn't work of course.

What is `f(x)` and where is it defined?

Unfortunately the documentation isn't available as a single page, making it a huge effort to search for the first occurrence. Searching for "lua f(x)" doesn't bear fruit either.

Explanation: now that I have received answers, I realize the problem was a misunderstanding. I incorrectly interpreted "f(x) is called only once" as "the line containing f(x) - `for i=1,f(x) do print(i) end` - will only return one value" and didn't pay enough attention to "**all three expressions are evaluated once, before the loop starts**".

Comment: `f(x)` is just an example, the `for` statement illustrates: (i) that the upper bound of a for loop can be a "complex" expression (ii) that this upper bound is evaluated before the loop starts which means that even if the `x` variable were modified inside of the loop, it wouldn't affect the number of iterations...

Comment: Please note that `f(x)` can not return two values when being used in expression list of numeric "for"-loop.  For example, the following code `function f(x) return x,-1 end; for i=10,f(1) do print(i) end` will not print anything.

Comment: The [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5) can be clearer by being concise and precise rather than expository like PIL. Use both.

Comment: To my misfortune, the Lua Reference Manual is a nerd that enjoys making me feel stupid and my brain hurt: `stat ::= for Name ‘=’ exp ‘,’ exp [‘,’ exp] do block end` o_O

Comment: You need to review Lua's basic syntax, be ause as if stands, you don't really have a strong enough knowledge of the foundation of the language to move on to control structures such as loops.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence clarifies it: **expressions are evaluated once, before the loop starts**.

Thus, **f(x) is called only once** is merely stating that the `expressions` will not be affected by potential changes in the loop.

For example, the following code (expressions are `i=1` and `x` in the second line):

```
x=5
for i=1,x do
  x = x - 1
  print(i, x)
end
print(x)
```

will produce the following output:

```
1   4
2   3
3   2
4   1
5   0
0
```

and will **not** produce the following output:

```
1   4
2   3
3   2
2
```

Answer (score 2):

`f(x)` is just a function which takes the argument `x` and returns a value that is used as the upper bound for the loop.

So for example, if the function `f(x)` calculates x² and you call it as `f(3)`, it would return the value of 9. The resulting `for` loop would look like this:

```
for i=1, f(3) do print(i) end
```

which is exactly the same as

```
for i=1, 9 do print(i) end
```